# How to use the `restrict` keyword in Cython?

Tags: python, cython, cpython

I'm using Cython in CPython 3.6 and I'd like to mark some pointers as "not aliased", to improve performance and be explicit semantically.

In C this is done with the `restrict` (`__restrict`, `__restrict__`) keyword. But how do I use `restrict` on my `cdef` variables from a Cython `.pyx` code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cython doesn't have syntax/support for the `restrict`-keyword (yet?). Your best bet is to code this function in C, most convenient is probably to use verbatim-C-code, e.g. here for a dummy example:

```
%%cython
cdef extern from *:
    """
    void c_fun(int * CYTHON_RESTRICT a, int * CYTHON_RESTRICT b){
       a[0] = b[0];
    }
    """
    void c_fun(int *a, int *b)
    
# example usage
def doit(k):
    cdef int i=k;
    cdef int j=k+1;
    c_fun(&i,&j)
    print(i)
```

Here I use Cython's (undocumented) define `CYTHON_RESTRICT`, which [is defined](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/c79ae55a7440459dae7667699284a72b09e89185/Cython/Utility/ModuleSetupCode.c#L310-L321) as

```
// restrict
#ifndef CYTHON_RESTRICT
  #if defined(__GNUC__)
    #define CYTHON_RESTRICT __restrict__
  #elif defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1400
    #define CYTHON_RESTRICT __restrict
  #elif defined (__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
    #define CYTHON_RESTRICT restrict
  #else
    #define CYTHON_RESTRICT
  #endif
#endif
```

so it works not only for C99-compliant c-compiler. In the long run however, it is probably best to define something similar and not to depend on undocumented features.